# How to navigate to a page inside another class library in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

There are a set of common pages that I want to use in multiple projects. Hence, I want to build a class library with those pages. The problem is I am not able to pass objects using NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Common;component/SomeName.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); method.

I know I can pass querystring. What I would like to know is...

1. Is there any limit to the number of strings you can pass in the querystring?
2. Is there any length limitation of the querystring?

Or better still,

Is there a better way of passing objects from an application to the pages inside a different class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the question "is there a better way". In addition to the solution you've mentioned some people like to use the app's state to pass parameters between objects. For example:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["parameter"] = param;
var parameter = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["parameter"];
```

Another option is to use a shared class. With complex objects I find it often easiest to use a static public member in a class which can be accessed from both of the projects.

Note that if you choose to use the query string navigation, some special characters in the query string may cause problems. If you can't control the content of the data which is passed between the pages, the shared class -solution is probably better for you. For example in one of our applications we're passing a web site's name in the query string. There's situations where those names can contain a '&' -character (like H&M) and if it does, the query string will break.

When navigating, if building the query strings gets cumbersome, you may check out the Caliburn.Micro and the Uribuilder class in it. It allows you to navigate with a rather nice (and fluent) syntax:

```
navigation.UriFor<CandidateDetailsPageViewModel>()
     .WithParam(x => x.CandidateId, candidate.Id)                
     .Navigate();
```

After navigation, the TryGetValue-method can be rather useful when parsing the parameters:

```
String parameter;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Parameter", out parameter)
```

More details for NavigationContext.QueryString is available [from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: You can Use HTTPUtility.UrlEncode or Uri.EscapeDataString to make strings safe to use in a QueryString

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. No there is no limit to the number of strings you can pass in a qyerystring
2. I believe the answer to this may be yes. I believe the standard is to have a url of < 2000 characters

For small items I usually just pass a query string to my pages. For more complex cases I have a shared static Domain class that both libraries reference. Then I can just access this variable statically really easily.